# Returning ImageSource from a Task - is this even possible?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, maui, imagesource

I seem to be going round in circles with this problem i'm having. The old code I was using is as follows:

```
private ImageSource LoadImg(string url)
    {
        WebClient MyWebClient = new WebClient();
        byte[] BytesFile = MyWebClient.DownloadData(url);
        Stream m2 = new MemoryStream(BytesFile);
        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => m2);

    }
```

And I could consume this really easily by just calling:

```
mainimg.Source = LoadImg(url);
```

Now I want to convert this into async and use httpClient as WebClient is being discontinued? So I tried doing this

```
private async Task<ImageSource> LoadImg2Async(url)
    {
        
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Firing LoadImg2");
        var httpResult = await Client.GetAsync(url);
        using var resultStream = await httpResult.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        //using var fileStream = File.Create(@"c:\dev\yaythisworks.png");
        //resultStream.CopyTo(fileStream);

        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => resultStream);

    }
```

Seems to make sense, at least a little bit. But, then how do I consume this return from a task? I have tried:

```
mainimg.Source = LoadImg2Async(url).Result;
```

but I can't get it to work

Does anyone have any ideas? I have honestly tried searching for answers on google this time, Can't find any answers on how to return from tasks.

Thank you so much

Andrew

Comment: when calling an `async` method, use `await`.  Do not use `Result`.  And you can load an `Image` directly from a url without doing all of this extra work

Comment: Sorry, I know I can load directly. I rigged this up as I'm doing extra work to convert a PDF to an image. So I knocked this up to try and find out where the issue is. How can I return an ImageSource from a task? When I do var s = await LoadImg2Async(url); the app just hangs and does nothing

Comment: @Jason My mistake, when I use
`mainimg.Source = await LoadImg2Async()` it doesn't hang like i said. It completes the task, but the imagesource of the image is not updated. so I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: have you tried writing to a file and using `ImageSource.FromFile`?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I have written to a file successfully, but ideally i'd rather not do that. I'm trying to iterate through a list of paths to pdf files, render each one as a thumbnail and display it in the listview. If at all possible i'd like to keep it in a stream, but I can't understand why it doesn't work. I've tried returning a stream and then converting to imagesource later on, but i have same problem.

Comment: not sure if `ReadAsStreamAsync` requires you to reset the stream to the begining - you might try that

Comment: I tried adding resultstream.position = 0. But I still have same problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: see Steve's answer - I completely missed that

Comment: @Jason - actually, it seems to be a new c# syntax. A local variable that stays alive until end of its scope. See link in Gabriel Luci's comment on my answer.

Comment: MAYBE RELEVANT: I've seen previous StackOverflow questions where people had problems using a stream from MediaPicker. Search for those Q&As, for Maui or Xamarin, and see if anyone found a solution (other than saving as a file). Its possible that the stream from httpResult has a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I was just expecting to be taught how to use google again :D. I never managed to get this working by returning a stream, I suspect ToolmakerSteve is correct and there is a problem. I managed to get it to work by returning a byte array `byte[] bytearray = await httpResult.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(); return bytearray;` but in order to consume this it seems very clunky. I had to create another bytearray using `byte[] myarray = await LoadImg2Async()` then set up a new memorystream using this, and then set the memory stream as the imagesource....

Comment: @AndrewTaylor - you could post your solution as "Your Answer" below. This would make it easier for future readers to find (any allow for better code formatting than in a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help, you helped me get on the right path!

It looks like it is not possible to return a stream from httpClient, I'm not sure why. When I was fiddling round it looks like the stream may be empty?! Anyway, the only way I found around this was to return bytes.

I had to change the Task return type to byte, and then return ms.ToArray();

```
private async Task<byte[]> LoadImg2Async(string pathtopdf)
    {   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pathtopdf);
        string pdfpathcorr = pathtopdf.Replace(@"Y:\", roothttpaddy);
        string url = pdfpathcorr.Replace(@"\", "/");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Corrected URL STRING = " + url);
                       
        var httpResult = await Client.GetAsync(url);
        byte[] bytearray = await httpResult.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        MemoryStream iStream = new MemoryStream(bytearray);
        PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument(iStream);
        PdfRendererSettings settings = new PdfRendererSettings();
        settings.DpiX = 10;
        settings.DpiY = 10;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        PdfPageRenderer renderer = new PdfPageRenderer(document.Pages[0]);
        renderer.ConvertPageToImage(ms, PdfPageImageFormat.Png, settings);
       

        //FileStream stm = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\dev\pdf " + fileid.ToString() + ".png");
        //renderer.ConvertPageToImage(stm, PdfPageImageFormat.Png, settings);
        ms.Position = 0;
       

 return ms.ToArray();
 
    }
```

Then to consume it I need to

```
byte[] bytearray = await LoadImg2Async(item.PDFPath);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytearray);

item.pdfpathconvert = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

It does work, but it seems very clunky. I am reading bytes from httpClient, then putting it in a stream, then converting to image and returning bytes from async task, and then I have to put it into a new stream to convert it into an ImageSource.

Any tips or suggestions?

I know my code might not be the most streamlined, I was just trying to go through it in a logical way at the moment, but any tips would be welcomed.

Thanks

Andrew